# How to design database SQLITE if the model include another list model

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm

My application need to store **Model_A** into SQLITE database, and **Model_A** include a ArrayList of **Model_B** as I describe in example code below:

```
class Model_A {
    String name;
    String description;
    int number;
    List<Model_B> list_Model_B;
}

class Model_B {
    String title;
    int quantity;

}
```

I searched and know that I can use GSON (or JSONObject) to convert Model_B to a json String file and store this json in Table of Model_A. But this way is not good for handling the data. I just want to do it without using GSON. 
I thought about create two table for Model_A and Model_B. Table of Model_A  will store a column  ID of Model_B. But this way only can store a object Model_B, not a List as I expect.

Can you let me know how to design the database reach my expect ? Or please suggest me a library which can help me on this case. Thanks.

Comment: How do you save a  Model_B.

Comment: @tinysunlight, as I mentioned, I can use GSON to convert Model_B to a json and save it.

Comment: Show me the code you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to relation database theory, you need to build *one-to-many* relationship, using two tables - the first one for **Model_A**, the second - for **Model_B**. 
Main idea of this relationship is connect two entities with *foreign keys* to have possibility for querying. 
Let's write some SQL for creating such relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE model_a (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    field TEXT NOT NULL 
);

-- Table for Model_B
CREATE TABLE model_b (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    model_a_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    field_2 TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY model_a_id REFERENCES model_a(_id) 
);
```

OK, we created two tables. But how can we get `List<Model_B>` from such scheme? 
There are two ways to do it. 
The first - make two selects for every `Model_A` class object: one for "details" of this object from `model_a` table, and one for list of `Model_B` elements:

```
SELECT *
FROM model_a
WHERE _id = ? 

-- For list of Model_B
SELECT *
FROM model_b
WHERE model_a_id = ?
```

The second way - get all information about one `Model_A` by one query. For this task we need special `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM model_a ma
    INNER JOIN model_b mb ON (ma._id = mb.model_a_id) 
WHERE (mb.model_a_id = ?)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a answer what I need. Thank you so much. I tried and it work perfect.